# XSLT Transformation: Concat, Substring, and Lowercase. Cannot get all three to work together

Tags: xml, xslt, substring, concatenation, lowercase

I am trying to use xslt to transform xml so that the output can be a username. I want to put the letters "gg_" and then the first letter of the first name and then the entire last name. I want the entire string to be in lowercase. I have successfully been able to concatenate, and use substring, but when I add in the lowercase my code doesn't work.

I've tried many different combinations, and iv been searching for a solution but I haven't been able to figure it out. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101862/converting-to-text-to-lowercase-in-nodes-and-child-nodes-in-xsl) seemed similar to this but I still could not get it to work.

XSLT: Working with just concat and substring

```
<GGUSERNAME><xsl:value-of select="concat('gg_',substring(ww:User/ww:Personal_Data/ww:First_Name,1,1),ww:User/ww:Person_Data/ws:Last_Name)"/></GGUSERNAME>
```

XSLT I've tried but cant get to work:

```
<GGUSERNAME><xsl:value-of select="concat('gg_',substring(lower-case(ww:User/ww:Personal_Data/ww:First_Name),1,1),ww:User/ww:Personal_Data/ww:Last_Name)"/></GGUSERNAME>

<GGUSERNAME><xsl:value-of select="lower-case(concat('gg_',substring(ww:User/ww:Personal_Data/ww:First_Name,1,1),ww:User/ww:Personal_Data/ww:Last_Name))"/></GGUSERNAME>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The functions concat() and substring() are available in XPath 1.0, but lower-case() requires XPath 2.0. The evidence suggests that you are probably using an XPath 1.0 processor. Your choices are to move to XPath 2.0 (with XSLT 2.0) if you can, or to use translate() if you can't. In future, remember with XSLT questions to say whether you are using 1.0 or 2.0, since the answers are likely to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You're much more likely to get good responses to questions on Stack Overflow if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

In this case, however, the solution is pretty obvious, even if the nature of your difficulty is not.  Assuming that the user's given name and family name are in variables $givenname and $familyname, and that we have already omitted any non-ASCII characters (if we're assigning userids of this form, I'm guessing we're working in that kind of organization, yes), then

```
concat('gg_',
       substring($givenname,1,1),
       $familyname)
```

gets you the concatenation you want, and for any ASCII string, `translate($string, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')` forces to lower-case.  Combining the two gives you something like this:

```
translate(concat('gg_',
                 substring($givenname,1,1),
                 $familyname),
          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
          'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

If you allow your users to have names with non-ASCII characters (bravo if you do) or the user's given and family names are not in variables with the names I have assumed, then of course you'll need to adjust this.  The adjustment for a larger character set will be a lot easier in XSLT 2.0 than in 1.0; in 2.0 there is a built-in `lower-case` function that simplifies life a good deal.